# Exporting Google Analytics via API call

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have analytics in my google dashboard, but I can't seem to find a way to export that data via an API, and then do whatever I want with that data, whether it be creating my own custom dashboards based on that data, or saving it to my DB. I searched everywhere, and can't seem to find anything helpful.

I checked out Core reporting API by google, but not sure it that's what I need. Any guidance would be appreciated. I should mention I am doing this in Javascript.

Comment: I can't understand your question. You say you need an API to export data from Google Analytics and the Core Reporting API from Google Analytics doesn't suit you?  Why not?

Comment: Hey @george sorry, that question was a little vague. After reading more and more through GA docs about Core Reporting API sounds like it will work, and I discovered finally how to get custom dimensions out of GA, which is why I didn't think it would work initially. I ran across this link from google. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ which lets you build queries, and I found the support custom dimensions. Thanks for the reply though man.